# Google+ SignInButton rendering error in Intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Am trying to add the Google+ sign in button to my app. In the layout viewer in the IDE, am getting this error:
[image]

but when I run the app on my mobile device, it renders just fine.

[image]

This is what my Android.manifest looks like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.DnD_Model"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Select the latest API level and it will get sorted.

Answer (score 0):

That how you can use latest API for rendering
[image]

Comment: This is exactly how it is in my project.Am using the latest API

Comment: download latest GooglePlayservices and copy latest Google Play services lib and replace old one. Probably it will help.

Comment: Am using the latest Google Play Services Lib (Rev 22) which i downloaded today :(

Answer (score 0):

Build and Run your app the error will automatically resolves.